# Pick a random record for a LARGE record set using arel / rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord, arel

I need to pick a random record for a VERY large ActiveRecord set.

What's the best way to do this?  I have something like this, but it still takes a long time.

```
Model.select('id').where("id = ? AND attr = ?", self.id, false).offset(rand(size)).limit(1)
```

Thank you

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/4329447/125816

Answer (score 0):

The usual techniques for this rely on generating a series of random numbers that represent the possible id's of records, and pulling back the relevant row.

You generally need to read the maximum (and maybe minimum) id's, and generate a bunch of random numbers between them. You generally can't guarantee that every id will exist, hence generating quite a few (or looping with a new random number each time) until you find one for which a row exists.

Answer (score -1):

```
Model.select('id').where("id = ? AND attr = ?", self.id, false).order("RANDOM()").first
```

Seems OK, but I feel like there is a better way.